# How to use .getElementsByClassName() on a for Loop to hide HTML elements

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, onclick

I'm trying to use getElementsByClassName, to hide HTML elements with onclick function.
I'm using a for loop to iterate the array created by getElementsByClassName.

But this way I'm getting a: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.circles..onclick

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance.

```
<div class="circle" id="red-circle"></div>
<div class="circle" id="blue-circle"></div>
<div class="circle" id="yellow-circle"></div>
```

===============================================

```
const circles = document.getElementsByClassName("circle")


    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        circles[i].onclick = () => {
            circles[i].style.display = "none"

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your arrow function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {

        circles[i].onclick = (e) => {
            e.currentTarget.style.display = "none"
        }
}
```

`e` refers to mouse event, and `currentTarget` is the clicked element.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot Saman Gholami.

Comment: @PauloRigter Your welcome. You can choose it as the best answer.